# Not getting any Checkbox Values from my AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a checkbox with values generated by SQL. I want to send the values of checkboxes that are checked by AJAX to be able to be used upon the same page in another element. But I am not getting any values in my test 'alert' box. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

```
<form id="numberOrderForm" action="index.php" method="POST">
    <div class="wrappers" id="multi-select1Wrapper">
        <h2>Area Code</h2>
        <select class="dropDownMenus" id="multi-select1" name="multi_select1[]" multiple="multiple">
            <?php
                //The query asking from our database
                $areaCodeSQL = "SELECT ac.Number AS `AreaCode`, ac.Name AS `AreaName`
                                FROM `AreaCodes` ac";                                                               //SQL query: From the table 'AreaCodes' select 'Number' and put into 'AreaCode', select Name and put into 'AreaName'

                $areaCodeResults = $conn->query($areaCodeSQL);                                                      // put results of SQL query into this variable

                if ($areaCodeResults->num_rows > 0) {                                                               // if num_rows(from $results) is greater than 0, then do this:
                    // output data of each row
                                foreach($areaCodeResults as $areaCodeResult)                                        //for each item in $areCodeResults do this:
                                    {
                                        $areaNameAndCode =  $areaCodeResult['AreaCode'] ." ". $areaCodeResult['AreaName'];  //get AreaCode and AreaName from query result and concat them
                                        $areaName = $areaCodeResult['AreaName'];                                    // get AreaName
                                        $areaCode = $areaCodeResult['AreaCode'];                                    //get AreaCode

                                        ?><option class="menuoption1" name="menuAreaCode" value="<?php echo $areaCode ?>"  ><?php echo $areaNameAndCode; ?></option><?php  //Create this option element populated with query result variables
                                    }
                } 

            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
```

My AJAX request:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#multi-select1").change(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var items=$("input[name='multi_select1']:checked").each(function () {
                    return this.value;
                }).get().join(',');



                $.post("index.php?data="+items, function(response){
                  alert(items);
                });        
           });           
        });
</script>
```

Comment: what do u get with alert(response) ?

Comment: I get the entire code for the page with ` alert(response)` :/

Comment: Yes, because you requested whole index.php page, ill write down example, but if u have full code, it would be easier.

Comment: do you mean you want the entire code for the page? what I have here is all the code this deals with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please put your script like this

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#multi-select1").change(function(e){
        items = $("#multi-select1").val()
            $.post("index.php?data="+items, function(response){
              alert(items);
            });        
       });           
    });
```

Comment: hey that worked! Thank you so much! This is outputing a string yeah? Something a query string can pick up and use?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at something like this at the top of your index.php file

```
if (isset($_GET["data"])) { 
    // do what you want to do with data, add it to that form etc...
    exit(); // add this in order to prevent script from processing rest of page.
}
```

this should do it.

Comment: Do you mean I have to put this at the top of my index.php file? does that mean my AJAX request is correct?

Comment: Yes, and yes, except that u need to output response, not items.

Comment: Ok, i done that. My AJAX request now looks like this: `$.post("index.php?data="+items, function(response){
             alert(response);
           });` But now my alert box contains the entire script of the page again

Comment: did u add what i wrote above at the top of your page? Even above <html> tag etc...

Comment: Ah, i put it in the top of the <head> section, but now thanks to sneha i have what I want. But thank you for your input :-)